# xcode organizer doesn't detect my device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I couldn't see my device in the organizer, although I installed the latest version on  my device, so the problem doesn't related to the iOS deployment target.
[image]

Comment: Is it your device detected in ituns?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you disconnected and reconnected the device? Restarted the device? Restarted Xcode? Restarted your computer?

Comment: Are you running OSX in VMWare?

Comment: @Yes I restart the Xcode and the iPhone.

Comment: @rckoenes what is the vmware ?

Comment: Does the device show up in iTunes ? What kind of Mac are you using ?

Comment: @Mani yes it is detected on itunes

Comment: @PaulR yes the device detected in the iTunes, I am using mac mini

Comment: what is your iOS version on iPhone and what is your xcode version?

Comment: my iOS version 7.1.1 and my Xcode version 5.1.1

Comment: on the device you have to _trust_ on the actual computer after you connected them with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using iOS 7 in your device then first time when you connect your device to system there is one popup will appear in your device for permission and you need to click on Trust, after that your device will be detected for development in xCode

Comment: actually I don't see any popup window ? w

Comment: How could I force the iPhone to  ask me for trust ?

Comment: if you click on don't trust then it will ask you every time when you connect your device to computer 

check this link http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5868